# Replacing characters in a file

Tags: python

I want to replace characters using encoding instructions in a text file.

My text file contains the line:

```
This is a message
```

I want to replace `a -> e`,`e -> a`,`s -> 3`

So the line reads:

```
Thi3 i3 e massega
```

I have tried the following code but it only changes one character in the line at one time.

```
import sys
import codecs

def encode():
  path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
  basename = "assgn2part1.txt"
  filename = path + "\\" + basename
  #file = open(filename, "rt")
  f = codecs.open(filename,encoding='utf-8')
  contents = f.read()


  print contents ,"\n"
  newcontents = contents.replace('a','e')
  newcontents = contents.replace('s', '3')

  print newcontents


  f.close()
```

Comment: You should use [**`os.path.join()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for composing paths correctly.

Comment: I gues the expected output is : `thi3 i3 e ma33ega`??

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: No need to guess. The question is explicit.

Answer (score 14):

Replace this:

```
newcontents = contents.replace('a','e')
newcontents = contents.replace('s', '3')
```

with this:

```
newcontents = contents.replace('a','e')
newcontents = newcontents.replace('s', '3')
```

Or better yet:

```
newcontents = contents.replace('a','e').replace('s', '3')
```

Your code only appears to attempt replacing 'a' with 'e', not 'e' with 'a'.  For that, you need the following:

```
import string
newcontents = contents.translate(string.maketrans("aes", "ea3"))
```

Comment: Note that the OP seems to want to replace `a -> e` and `e -> a`, which will only work if done in parallel, because sequential execution of the replacements will lead to `tea` --(`a -> e`)--> `tee` --(`e -> a`)--> `taa`, which is probably not, what the OP wants to have. So replace is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: +1 for [**`str.translate()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). This is *the* way to go!

Comment: I guess they're supposed to achieve that without built-in functions.

Comment: @thg435: Like without [**`str.replace()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?

Comment: @thg435: I saw that, but the OP did use `str.replace()`.

Comment: Since `string.maketrans()` is depcrecated since Python 3.1, you have to use `str.maketrans` with equal results.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple gist you can see and get some help

```
//First read the contents of file in a variable and replace what you want using .replace() function

x = open("e:/a.txt" )
s=x.read().replace("a", "xy" ) 
x.close()

//Now open the file in write mode and write the string with replaced

x=open("e:/a.txt","w")
x.write(s)
x.close
```

Comment: It seems unrelated to the question. The main problem of OP is how to replace, rather than IO.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> strs="this is a message"
>>> strs="".join(['a' if x=='e' else 'e' if x=='a' else '3' if x=='s' else x for x in strs])
>>> print(strs)
thi3 i3 e ma33ega
```

**or as Robert suggested**, use a dictionary

```
>>> strs="this is a message"
>>> dic={'a':'e','e':'a','s':'3'}
>>> strs="".join((dic.get(x,x) for x in strs))
>>> print(strs)
thi3 i3 e ma33ega
```

**or:**

```
>>> strs="this is a message"
>>> dic={'a':'e','e':'a','s':'3'}
>>> new_strs=''
>>> for x in strs:
     if x in dic:
        new_strs += dic[x]
     else:
        new_strs += x
>>> print(new_strs)

thi3 i3 e ma33ega
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this approach, but at least use a `dict` instead of a bunch of `if`/`else` conditions.

Comment: @robert suggestion implemeted

Comment: +1, I'd suggest making the last one more readable for a beginner (i.e. a loop instead of a comprehension and if-else instead of get).

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> contents = codecs.open('foo.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
>>> print contents
This is a message.

>>> print contents.replace('s', '3')
Thi3 i3 a me33age.
```

*Note:* If you want the second replace to work, you should do it on *newcontents*:

```
newcontents = contents.replace('a','e')
newcontents = newcontents.replace('s', '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex as well

```
newcontents = re.sub(r"a","e",contents)
newcontents = re.sub(r"s","3",newcontents)
```